# Images works locally, but not on github pages

Tags: image, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have problem with images on [my page](https://iluzjonista.github.io/boilerplate-modules/) ;
[github link](https://github.com/Iluzjonista/boilerplate-modules)

Locally i see everything, images works, but when i published it on ghp, images have disappeared with 404 error. I have no idea why it's not working...

I read old questions and i don't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a problem. I published branch master/docs, so github pages omitted the whole src directory, so he had no way to see the images. I fixed it with publishing whole branch master.